# WebView en Android Studio que funcione igual que en el navegador

Tags: java, android

Tengo un *WebView* en un proyecto en *Android Studio*, este *WebView* contiene o carga una página de radio online (*streaming*) hecha en *listen2myradio*... El *WebView* carga correctamente puedo escuchar la emisión y todo bien. El problema es que cuando ejecuto la página desde un computador la música comienza a sonar automáticamente. En cambio desde el *WebView* tengo que apretar el botón de *play* para que comience a sonar... ¿Existe una manera de que la música se reproduzca automáticamente al cargar el *WebView* al igual que en el navegador?

Código que tiene el *WebView*:

```
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Comment: Podes agregar el codigo html y javascript para ver que es lo que se carga en el webview?